# Correctly created and opened an ofstream .txt file however i can't write to it

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm making a program that compares a string entered by the user to another one taken from an ifstream Gfile, and if the comparison is True, i want to save that ID in an ofstream RFile, and here is my code:

```
void Dropbox::SafetyVerifByString(string GivenID, string GivenFile, string ReturnFile)
{
    ifstream GFile(GivenFile.c_str());
    ofstream RFile("Results.txt");
    string Res="";

    if(!GFile.is_open() || !RFile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"Error: One Of The Files Could Not Open!";
    }
else
    {
        while(getline(GFile,Email,':') && getline(GFile,ID)) // GFile contains a 100 lines like this mickeykats@gmail.com:fa289bcf529dc73c1e0376652af1299332946b59
        {
            if(GivenID==ID) //this is where my problem resides
            {
                Res=Email+":"+ID;
                cout<<Res<<endl;
                RFile<<Res<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    GFile.close();
    RFile.close();
}
```

i tried putting the `RFile<<Res<<endl;` above and outside that if statement and it worked, it literally works anywhere but inside that if statement, and i want it nowhere but inside that statement, i've been stuck here from 2 AM till 5 AM and it is driving me crazy, there is literally no reason for it to do that .. thanks for your time.

PS: while i'm at it, if there is any better way to read from a file containing hundreds of lines each line has the following format -> Email:Code in a way that stores Email in a string variable and code in another string variable, please let me know, if what i came up with (through internet research) is good, let me know too, thank you.

Edit1: i added a `Cout<<ID<<endl;` right after `if(ID=GivenID)` just to show you that ID is correctly getting the desired value, and i did a bunch of trie to show you the result:

[image: Here is the execution of the whole program]

Edit2: i did some more testing and it seems like some of the 4 text files i have work okay and the function does print to Results and in some others it doesn't, i'm even more confused ... it my have something to do with the encrypted pass in some of the files and the character that constitute it, here is a preview of the files:

[image: File 1]
[image: File 2]
[image: File 3]
[image: File 4]

Comment: By "inside that if statement" you do mean inside the `else` branch, correct?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: What's the sample contents of ```GivenID```? Is it something like 'mickeykats@gmail.com:fa289bcf529dc73c1e0376652af1299332946b59' ?

Comment: Well if it does not work in the if statement then it means the condition is not true. Are you absolutely sure that `GivenID` equals `ID` including any space tabs etc. I would print them out and manually check all 100. `std::cout << ">" << GivenID << "< >" << ID << "<    Good: " << (GivenID==ID) << "\n";`

Comment: I agree with @MartinYork. I just copied and pasted your code into a new file and stepped through it. It's working fine on a sample file it threw together with 3 email:ID combinations. Are you sure that the ID being passed into your function is correct?

Comment: i'm no sure it is correct but i tested this code a hundred times and i did a cout on ID right after giving it a value and it is taking correct, the ID==GivenID is working perfect, i tested it on multiple addresses from the file and it does give the desired result, no errors no warnings nothing wrong with the code it is working perfectly yet it does not write to the file ..

Comment: i sincerely hope that those email addresses are fake ...

Comment: it's an exercise proposed by my university, the files contain real addresses that were hacked and obtained from Dropbox in the past, they're public and there's nothing to worry about now